# Is there a way to lazy load jQuery itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

jQuery supports many types of lazy loading for images, plugins, etc.  But I want to load jQuery itself lazily, i.e. only if it is actually used on the page.

90% of my website does not use jQuery.  I would rather add jQuery lazy-loading on all the pages then tediously include jQuery explicitly only in those pages that use it.  I do not want 90% of the pages to suffer the performance hit of loading jQuery.

It could be a small wrapper that defines '$', 'jQuery', etc. and dynamically loads jQuery on the first usage of one of those functions.

According to PageSpeed Insights, inserting jquery into a bare-bones page adds 1 full second of render-blocking time on Mobile.

https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.somacon.com%2Fwithjquery.html

https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.somacon.com%2Fwithoutjquery.html

Comment: Are you using a bundler ? eg: webpack

Comment: Perhaps there are vanilla JS ways of acheiving the functionality without depending upon jQuery at all.

Comment: Change that to "most likely"

Comment: Also fwiw, using a cdn of a widely used jquery version is probably a negligible hit as most of your users will already have it cached

Comment: *"performance hit"* - have you quantified this?  Modern browsers cache the *parsed* version of js files, so if your pages all load the same src= (either a CDN or your local) then it will only be the first time it's seen that there's an impact.

Comment: You might want to give [https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) a visit, if you're not using it very much, it might be better to not use it at all.

Comment: If all the scripts that use jQuery are defer-loaded, simply defer-load jQuery from a CDN as well. That will leverage both “lazy loading” and CDN cache re-use later on.

Comment: I'm not using a bundler.  I am using vanilla JS where possible, but some things like ajax calls are magical with jQuery.  Yes, I quantified and jquery adds 1 full second of render-blocking time:  https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.somacon.com%2Fwithoutjquery.html    vs   https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.somacon.com%2Fwithjquery.html

Comment: For AJAX, I think [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is better - and that doesn't need jQuery at all. :)